# vertical align content using grid in react

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, antd

I found many ui library or framework's grid system has no easy way to merely center vertically a block with width. I just want says a block with max-width of 200px in the center, how can I avoid using custom css to style it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-layout-ch745

doc: https://ant.design/components/grid/

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the centering is easy. In a 24 column grid you can use the `Col` component and play around the span numerics to make sure width is same left and right. For example, these are all column settings that would get you centering:

- `<Col span={12} offset={6}>`
- `<Col span={10} offset={7}>`
- `<Col span={8} offset={8}>`
- `<Col span={6} offset={8}>`

Simply pick a span that is an event number, and the offset equals (24 - span) / 2.

The problem is the max-width: 200px. To restrict the max width to a value no matter what screen size it is, I am afraid you're going to have to write custom CSS for it, simply because there is nothing that will get you a specific value without you specifying what that value is.

In that case, I suggest creating one row and one column that spans that entire row, and use flex to center your element:

```html
<Col span={24}>
    <div style="display: 'flex'; justify-content: 'center';">
        <div style="flex: 1; max-width: '200px'">
        </div>
    </div>
</Col>
```

Comment: why need a Col when you write your own flexbox?